# Show that $f'(f(z))$ omits $0$ and $c$ (Entire functions)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

Assume that $f$ is entire and that  $z\to f(f(z))$ has no fixed points. Consider $$g(z)=\frac{f(f(z))-z}{f(z)-z}$$ which is an entire function. I have shown that $g$ is constant i.e. $$f(f(z))=cf(z)+z(1-c)$$ for some $c\in C\setminus\{0,1\}$. Why does it follow that $f'(f(z))$ omits $0$ and $c$?

Comment: Differentiate the identity. That will take care of $c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $f'(f(z)) = c$ gives an immediate contradiction – but I don't see that for $f'(f(z)) = 0$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I forgot about omitting $0$. That needs a different argument.

Comment: @DanielFischer I showed that it omits $c$ but $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating the identity

$$f(f(z)) = cf(z) + z(1-c)$$

yields

$$f'(f(z))\cdot f'(z) = cf'(z) + (1-c)\,.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Since $1-c \neq 0$, it follows that $f'(f(z))$ never attains the value $c$. Therefore we can rearrange $(\ast)$ into

$$f'(z) = \frac{1-c}{f'(f(z)) - c}\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$

which shows that $f'$ never attains the value $0$.

Comment: Substituting $f'(z)=0$ in $(*)$ would also give the contradiction directly. (I failed to make the mental leap that $f'(z) \ne 0$ implies $f'(f(z)) \ne 0$ :)

Comment: Indeed. [insert something about a forest and trees]

Comment: @DanielFischer Picard's little theorem implies that $f'(f(z))$ is constant. Does that mean that $f'(z)$ is constant?

Comment: @seht111 Yes. If $g'(g(z))$ is constant for a holomorphic $g \colon U \to U$ with a connected $U$, then $g'$ is constant. For either $g$ is constant, and then $g'(w) = 0$ for all $w\in U$, or $g(U)$ is open, and then the identity theorem says that $g'$ must be constant on $U$.

Comment: And here, we next deduce that our $f$ is a polynomial of degree $1$, $f(z) = az+b$. Since $f(f(z)) \neq z$ for all $z$ it follows that $a^2 = 1$. If we had $a = -1$, it would however follow that $f(f(z)) = z$ for all $z$, so $a = 1$, i.e. $f$ is a translation. And $c = 2$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Why does it follow that $a^2=1$?

Comment: @seht111 Because $f(f(z)) = af(z) + b = a(az+b) + b = a^2z + (a+1)b$, and for $\alpha \neq 1$, $z \mapsto \alpha z + \beta$ has the fixed point $\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$. So the absence of fixed points implies $a^2 = 1$ [since $f$ itself cannot have fixed points, we could directly deduce $a = 1$ without going through $a^2$].